# VBA works stepping through but not running

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code below works when I step through but not when I run it. I want each tab to be saved as a csv file in my chosen folder. When I run it, the code saves the first sheet multiple times named after each tab. Hope this is clear, see code below.

```
Sub SaveAsCsv()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim xDir As String
Dim folder As FileDialog
Set folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = folder.SelectedItems(1)
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
xWs.SaveAs xDir & "\" & xWs.Name, xlCSV
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

delete the created file and then run again. because F8 has already created the file and while you run f5 it does not know where to save

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I run it I select a new folder which is empty for the files to be saved. It saves Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 etc but the contents of each csv file is the same as Sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Your naming is a bit confusing. Therefore I have changed the variable names. But now the code works.

```
Sub SaveAsCsv()
    ' 53

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim Dialog As FileDialog

    Set Dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If Dialog.Show Then
        Folder = Dialog.SelectedItems(1)
        For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            Ws.SaveAs Folder & "\" & Ws.Name, xlCSV
        Next
    End If
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, "Action report"
End Sub
```

Note that exiting the procedure before its end isn't good programming practice, akin to the use of `GoTo` commands. Try and avoid either whenever you can. In this case it's easy to do, using the same IF statement you have anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions. I have tried this code but am getting the same issue. It works when I step through but not when I run it. All the csv files that save have the same content, rather than the content in the tab the file is named after.

Comment: The code is tested. It works perfectly. Therefore any problem must arise from your setup. Perhaps your disk drive can't follow the speed of the code. Perhaps your installation of Excel is corrupt. I would put my money on virus intervention. Unless you happen to know that your hard disk may not match the computer's configuration (not the original disk), clean viruses from the machine and re-install Windows.